# how to put second time exist is 2 or so on?

Tags: java, hashmap

how to add if my data first time exist, value will put 1, if the data already exist into hashmap, need put 2 and so on.

below is my coding:

```
public ArrayList<String> processJson(JSONObject json) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < hits.length(); i++) {
        // to make sure funny/stupid/illogical resp back from ES is caught and ignored!
        try {
            JSONArray tag = item.getJSONArray("tag");
            System.out.println("tag" + hm.entrySet());
            if (source.equalsIgnoreCase("trkd")) {
                for (int j = 0; j < tag.length(); j++) {
                    if (j == 0) {
                        if (!hm.containsKey(tag.toString(0))) {
                            hm.put(tag.getString(0), 1);
                        } else {
                            hm.put(tag.getString(0), new Integer(j + 1));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hm.containsValue(1)) {
                output.add(out);
            } else {
                output.add(out);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

if the value equal to 1, output just add.
but now, my hashmap all is value 1, how to do?

Comment: What is this code supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the compare on

```
if (!hm.containsKey(tag.toString(0))) {
```

but updating with

```
hm.put(tag.getString(j), 1);
```

so `j != 0`

I guess the contains should also be using `j`

**Edit**

As @Adi points out
*Plus, the check the condition 'j==0', this is unnecessary and prevents you from processing beyond first tag.*

Comment: Plus, the check the condition 'j==0', this is unnecessary and prevents you from processing beyond first tag.

Comment: @Adi Thanks I will add that to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Lots of weird things going on in your code.

1. Pretty sure `tag.toString(int)` and `tag.getString(int)` are not equivalent. I bet you only wanted to use `getString`
2. Why is everything happening in `j==0` clause? Your loop would effectively only be doing useful stuff only once.
3. Were you actually trying to code something like this?

   ```
   if (!hm.containsKey(tag.getString(j))) {
       hm.put(tag.getString(j), 1);
   } else {
       hm.put(tag.getString(j), hm.get(tag.getString(j)+1);
   }
   ```
4. The following code doesn't require an `if-else` since you're doing the same thing in both cases.

   ```
   if (hm.containsValue(1)) {
       output.add(out);
   } else {
       output.add(out);
   }
   ```

   Can be replaced with:

   ```
   output.add(out)
   ```
5. I don't think you're explaining very well what you need to do. From whatever I could gather using my code from #3 should get you exactly what you want.

Comment: explain for no 2: i only need add j=0, mean first element in that array.

Comment: for example for my tag value will be [ "abc123", "67",u12"]

Comment: how to add the hashap when abc123 first time is abc123,1, then second time abc123 is abc123,2?

Comment: My code does what I think you want it to do. Use my code from #3 and tell me if you get what you want or not.

Comment: Coding No 3 not i expected result. Can Hashmap is multiple mapping? For example [ "abc123", "67",u12"] in first time already at Hashmap = abc123,1, second time is [ "abc123", "69",u1"] hashmap should be abc123, 2 and so on.. This hashmp don't replaced my first entry. How should i do?

Comment: `if (source.equalsIgnoreCase("trkd")) {` what is this source?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a HashMap, you should use a Multimap. Google Guava provides one.

Comment: i already try, but i have error 'SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SearchServlet] in context with path [/NewsWebSvc] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Multimap'